# Python EbaySDK Merchandising API returns 'Invalid CONSUMER-ID specified' error

Tags: python, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I've been using the Python EbaySDK to query ebay for items etc; however I've run into a problem when attempting to use the production Merchandising API with the following code:

```
import ebaysdk
from ebaysdk.merchandising import Connection as Merchandising
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError

try:
    api = Merchandising(domain='svcs.ebay.com',config_file=None, appid="APP_ID")
    response = api.execute('getMostWatchedItems', {'maxResults': 10})
    print(response.dict())
    print(response.reply)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

Where APP_ID is replaced by my production app_id for the developer account. This however returns the following error:

```
u'getMostWatchedItems: Domain: Marketplace, Severity: Error, errorId: 9, Invalid CONSUMER-ID specified'
{'errorMessage': {'error': {'category': 'Application', 'domain': 'Marketplace', 'severity': 'Error', 'message': 'Invalid CONSUMER-ID specified', 'subdomain': 'MarketplaceCommon', 'errorId': '9'}}}
```

I've looked through the documentation and can see that the consumer-id is indeed the app-id that I'm passing. I've tried swapping the keys by creating a second account but the error persists. Any help on this would be most welcome!

Comment: I've got the same issue, although I did notice that when I switch the domain to "svcs.sandbox.ebay.com" and appid to my sandbox id, the request succeeds (with no data, since it's the sandbox I guess).